# mono, c#, sockets, performance

Tags: c#, unix, mono, sockets

I developed simple async server that listens to unix socket and sync client that send the some small piece of data. Time between moment when i send data from client to the moment when server receives them is completly random, from 1 to 9 seconds. I wonder why is the reason? Server is implemented as shown in msdn example here (using beginReceive): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te.aspx

```
EndPoint ep = new UnixEndPoint(_fileName);
_socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.Unix, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);

try
{
     _socket.Bind(ep);
     _socket.Listen(_maxConnectionsInQuee);

     while(true)
     {
         done.Reset();
         _socket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), null);
         done.WaitOne();
     }
}
```

And in the client:

```
EndPoint ep = new UnixEndPoint(_fileName);
_socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.Unix, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
_socket.Connect(ep);
byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
_socket.Send(bytes);
```

Method that sends data to the server is called from webservice method (running via xsp2).

Comment: What are you using as the client?

Comment: Btw, I'm editing the title. These are not unix domain sockets.

Comment: Actually they are. I'm using UnixEndPoint from Mono.Unix and this is pretty much the only difference. I've added some code to the post above for clarification

Comment: That is weird. Xsp2 itself (well, mod-mono-server2) uses unix sockets to communicate with mod_mono and I've never seen a delay there.

Comment: hmm... to me it's weird. Could you point me to xsp2 sources when the communication is made?? I may be able to figure it out having working example

Comment: http://anonsvn.mono-project.com/viewvc/trunk/xsp/src/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It occures that unix sockets in mono are ok :). I had some threading issues which were completely unrelated to Mono.Unix and unix domain sockets. Thanks all for your help.

Comment: Hi, would this work on windows, or is it strictly unix bound?