# Unix sockets in c#

Tags: c#, windows, sockets, unix, mono

I'm trying to employ Mono's UnixEndPoint, but fail before even getting to use it. I'm running Xamarind + .net 4.5 on a 64bit windows 7 system.

Here's a bit of code proving that not a single combination works:

```
foreach(SocketType st in Enum.GetValues(typeof(SocketType)))
    foreach(ProtocolType pt in Enum.GetValues(typeof (ProtocolType)))
    {
        try{
            socket = new Socket (AddressFamily.Unix, st, pt);
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", st, pt);
        }
        catch{

        }
    }
```

Basically, all combinations produce a socket error of some sort.

Over here, someone used it apparently - [mono, c#, sockets, performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783660/mono-c-sockets-performance) - is this supposed to work on windows at all? I might just be very silly trying to use UNIX sockets on WINDOWS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see any reason to expect this to work on Windows.

The `AddressFamily` value is passed directly by .NET's `Socket` class to the native [`WSASocket()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms742212(v=vs.85).aspx) function to create the unmanaged socket object. By default, only `AddressFamily.InterNetwork` and `AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6` (corresponding to `AF_INET` and `AF_INET6`, respectively) are supported by Windows, unless you have other network providers installed (NetBIOS would be an obvious alternative that might be commonly found on a Windows installation).

From the documentation:

> The values currently supported are AF_INET or AF_INET6, which are the Internet address family formats for IPv4 and IPv6. Other options for address family (AF_NETBIOS for use with NetBIOS, for example) are supported if a Windows Sockets service provider for the address family is installed.

It makes sense that `AddressFamily.Unix` would work on a *Unix* machine, but unless you have installed a provider on your Windows machine that provides specific support for that address family, it should in fact fail on that Windows machine.

**Note:** as of August 2018, Windows provides limited support for AF_UNIX sockets, to allow for specific [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) scenarios. There are important restrictions, among those being: only stream-oriented sockets are supported; and ancillary data (used e.g. to pass file information or user credentials) is not supported. A given socket can be used to communicate within Windows, within a WSL instance, or between Windows and a WSL instance, but not for multiple of these scenarios.

**For now, it appears that there continues to be no support in desktop .NET version, and [only limited support in .NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.unixdomainsocketendpoint?view=netstandard-2.1&viewFallbackFrom=netframework-4.7.2).** Once the `UnixDomainSocketEndPoint` support is finalized in .NET Core, I suppose it's possible that will work its way back to the desktop .NET version.

For more details, see:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/af_unix-comes-to-windows/
and
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windowswsl-interop-with-af_unix/